# Problem with Chart.js - Can't see the values in the graph

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, chart.js

I am making a Flask application to visualize some data through a web. For this, I use Chart.js to let the user see the data in donut or bar charts. The thing is, I'd like the charts to also display the values ​​they have inside them, so I use ChartDataLabels. My problem is that if I put the graphs in a function in the following way, I see a graph like the one I want to represent, with its values ​​within the same graph (don't pay much attention to the values ​​because they are totally false):

```
function chartOEE(valors) {
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    const background_color = ['#33a3ec', '#ffce55', '#4ac1c1', '#ff00ff00'];
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: ['Availability', 'Performance', 'Quality'],
            datasets: [{
                data: valors,
                backgroundColor: background_color,
                borderWidth: 10,
                borderColor: "#fbfbfb"
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                display: false
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1000,
                animateRotate: true,
                render: false
            },
            plugins: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Pieces fabricated"
                },
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom'
                }
            }
        },
        plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
        options: {
            plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                    color: ['black', 'black', 'black', 'white'],
                    font: { weight: 'bold', size: '14px' }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[image: Graphic like the one I want]

But instead, if I modify them so that they update the data every x time, I don't see anything and it shows me the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'x')**

```
var ctx_pieces = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
const background_color2 = ['#33a3ec', '#ff6384'];
Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);

var chart_pieces = new Chart(ctx_pieces, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: ['OK', 'NOK'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [0, 0],
            backgroundColor: background_color2,
            borderWidth: 10,
            borderColor: "#fbfbfb"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            display: false
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 1000,
            animateRotate: true,
            render: false
        },
        plugins: {
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: "Pieces fabricated"
            },
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'bottom'
            }
        }
    },
    /*
     * Problem is her.
     * If I comment this lines, the graph
     * shows correctly but without the value labels.
     */
    plugins: [ChartDataLabels],
    options: {
        plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: 'black',
                font: { weight: 'bold', size: '14px' }
            }
        }
    }
});

/* Function to update the graph periodically. */
function actualizarGrafico() {
    $.get('/pieces', function(data) {
        chart_pieces.data.datasets[0].data[1] = data.pieces_nok;
        chart_pieces.data.datasets[0].data[0] = data.pieces_ok;
        chart_pieces.update();
    });
}

/* Update chart every 5 seconds. */
setInterval(actualizarGrafico, 5000);
```

The result I see. As you can see, it does not show any graph:

[image: The graph is not showd]

Has anyone struggled with this? How do I solve it?

Thanks and sorry for bothering )

The complete console error (through the console I see that the data is sent correctly, but it throws me the following error):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'x')
    at l (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:1172)
    at Object.f [as positioner] (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:2773)
    at $ (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:7328)
    at Object.draw (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:9562)
    at Object.afterDatasetsDraw (chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js:7:12091)
    at d (chart.js:13:1113)
    at Qs._notify (chart.js:19:82747)
    at Qs.notify (chart.js:19:82568)
    at wn.notifyPlugins (chart.js:19:101170)
    at wn._drawDatasets (chart.js:19:97064)
```

[image: Console log]

Comment: I don't see any issues. Looks working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/codething/8wgyh7ap/16/

Comment: The code seems correct, through the console I see that the data is sent correctly. I read them from a SQLITE3 database and send them via AJAX and have checked that they are sent correctly. The code of the graph also seems correct, since they are displayed correctly and if I make a function that sends random values then the labels are displayed correctly, but when the data that is sent is the real one, the error that I mention occurs (but if I remove the ChartDataLabels plugin displays the chart correctly). It's just something that doesn't make sense to me, could it be a bug in chart.js?

Comment: You can debug by console logging and observing your data in each interval leaving ChartDataLabels as is.

Comment: It is the first thing to check and the data is sent correctly :(

Comment: @CodeThing do you have any idea why this happens?